# Is it possible to render polygons as tiles on Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gis, geojson

I'm trying to render multiple polygons with some serious performance issues.

I currently retrieve via webservice a big GeoJSON file (~2MB) with lots of polygons and multipolygons.

I managed to render all of them as `GeoJsonLayer` and adding them later to my `GoogleMap` instance with no problems, except for some polygons not filling up the background color (check this GitHub issue [#257](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/257)). This is a known bug as I can see.

The main problem is the amount of points that are composing my polygons, making the performance really bad, specially on low-end devices.

Is there any way to render each polygon as a Tile, PNG, Image or anything that can be placed on top of the map to increase the performance?

If not, which would be the best way to draw that amount of polygons?

This is my code sample i'm currently using (Android):

```
for(int i = 0; i < pages.length(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) pages.get(i);
    JSONObject geometry = obj.getJSONObject("geometry");
    GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mGoogleMap, geometry);
    GeoJsonPolygonStyle style = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
    style.setStrokeColor(Color.WHITE);
    style.setStrokeWidth(2F);
    style.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
    style.setPolygonFillColor(Color.GREEN);
    layer.addLayerToMap();
}
```

Comment: I've finally tried out a third party GIS library. Anyways, a solution is welcome in case that anyone else is also facing this issue.